# FLANN Autotune Stuck at "Estimating number of checks"

Tags: python, flann

I'm trying to use FLANN on Python with a training set matrix of 6,000,000 x 100.  I am building the index with the following commands:

```
flann = pyflann.FLANN()
params = flann.build_index(trainX, algorithm="autotuned", target_precision=0.9, sample_fraction=0.1, log_level="info")
```

I get lots of cross-validation results, the final lines shows this:

```
***Earlier results omitted***
KDTree using params: trees=32
  Nodes  Precision()   Time(s)   Time/vec(ms)  Mean dist
---------------------------------------------------------
       1      0.084    0.15658    0.15658     2.9036
       2      0.098    0.15296    0.15296      2.097
       4      0.137    0.15613    0.15613     1.6675
       8      0.213    0.15454    0.15454     1.3968
      16      0.324    0.16528    0.16528     1.2296
      32      0.445    0.16481    0.16481     1.1253
      64      0.567    0.20677    0.20677     1.0767
     128      0.685    0.28533    0.28533     1.0437
     256      0.777    0.42094    0.42094      1.027
     512      0.863    0.73215    0.73215     1.0142
    1024      0.916     1.2737     1.2737     1.0062
Start linear estimation
     768      0.895    0.94626    0.94626     1.0086
     896      0.903      1.073      1.073     1.0077
     832      0.899     1.0092     1.0092     1.0081
KDTree buildTime=71.6163, searchTime=1.00915
----------------------------------------------------
Autotuned parameters:
algorithm : 1
trees : 8
----------------------------------------------------
Computing ground truth
Estimating number of checks
  Nodes  Precision()   Time(s)   Time/vec(ms)  Mean dist
---------------------------------------------------------
       1      0.445      3.053      3.053     2.0321
       2      0.445     2.7963     2.7963     2.0321
       4      0.457     3.2702     3.2702      1.514
       8      0.475     3.0651     3.0651      1.321
      16      0.503     3.0939     3.0939     1.1812
      32      0.527     3.1058     3.1058     1.1132
      64       0.57     3.6118     3.6118     1.0734
     128      0.608     3.6885     3.6885     1.0467
     256      0.642     3.3601     3.3601     1.0306
     512      0.672     3.2895     3.2895     1.0187
    1024      0.712     3.7659     3.7659     1.0087
    2048      0.732     4.7198     4.7198     1.0047
    4096      0.745     5.3416     5.3416     1.0027
    8192      0.757     7.7298     7.7298     1.0012
   16384      0.762     11.114     11.114     1.0006
   32768       0.77     17.114     17.114     1.0001
   65536      0.772      31.03      31.03          1
  131072      0.772     61.822     61.822          1
  262144      0.772     133.58     133.58          1
  524288      0.773     284.51     284.51          1
 1048576      0.773     605.73     605.73          1
 2097152      0.773     1437.5     1437.5          1
 4194304      0.773     3971.2     3971.2          1
 8388608      0.773     6485.3     6485.3          1
16777216      0.773     6476.2     6476.2          1
33554432      0.773     6456.1     6456.1          1
67108864      0.773     6494.2     6494.2          1
```

It seems to me that a KDTree has been chosen (algorithm=1) with 8 trees.   But now the last series of tests "Estimating number of checks" is stuck.  It has been running overnight already but it hasn't finished.  I think it's because the precision cannot reach my target of 0.9 so it just keeps increasing the nodes.

Can someone advise me on how to proceed?  Should I just kill it and manually specify a kd-tree with the "Autotuned Parameters"?  What is this "number of checks" that it is calculating anyway - I thought the number of trees and nodes have already been found?